# ng-table TypeError: Cannot set property '$data' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ng-table to display information from an API call which I group like the example on the [website](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/21).

However, the example on the website makes use of static information where as I need to make a new API call each time. When I don't include the   $`scope.$watch('groupby', function(value)` function, I am amble to display the table for the first, initial call.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ngTable','ui.bootstrap','dialogs'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope,$log, $rootScope, $modal, TimeService, EventServiceAPI, $filter, ngTableParams) {
    var datum = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
    $scope.datum = datum;
    var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);


    var findAllEvents = function(timestampdata) {
        EventServiceAPI.query({start: timestampdata, end: timestampdata + 3*24*60*60}).$promise.then(function(data) {

            //var data = $filter('orderBy')(data, 'event.startHour');

            $scope.$watch("data", function () {
                $scope.tableParams.reload();
            }); 

            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 100          // count per page

            }, {
                groupBy: function(item) {
                    return 'Start vanaf ' + item.event.startHour + ' uur';
                },
                total: data.length,
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                            $filter('orderBy')(data, 'event.startHour') :
                            data;

                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch('groupby', function(value){
                $scope.tableParams.settings().groupBy = value;
                console.log('Scope Value', $scope.groupby);
                console.log('Watch value', this.last);
                console.log('new table',$scope.tableParams);
                $scope.tableParams.reload();
            });
        })
    };    

    findAllEvents(timestamp);

    $scope.getEarlier = function() {
        datum -= (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        $scope.datum = datum;
        var timestamp = Math.round(datum/1000);
        console.log(timestamp);
        findAllEvents(timestamp);

    };
});
```

**EDIT:**

I am now able to display the data, however the groups are not displayed:

```
var datum = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
    $scope.datum = datum;
    var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);

    EventServiceAPI.query({start: timestamp, end: timestamp + 3*24*60*60}).$promise.then(function(data) { $scope.data = data; initlizeTable(); });


    var initlizeTable = function() {
        // Table
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 100          // count per page

        }, {
            groupBy: function(item) {
                return 'Start vanaf ' + $scope.data.event.startHour + ' uur';
            },
            total: $scope.data.length,
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                var data = EventServiceAPI.query({start: timestamp, end: timestamp + 3*24*60*60});
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                        $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, 'event.startHour') :
                            $scope.data;

                        $defer.resolve($scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }, $scope: { $data: $scope.data }
        });

        $scope.$watch('groupby', function(value){
            $scope.tableParams.settings().groupBy = value;
            console.log('Scope Value', $scope.groupby);
            console.log('Watch value', this.last);
            console.log('new table',$scope.tableParams);
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });

        $scope.$watch('data', function(value){
            $scope.tableParams.settings().groupBy = value;
            console.log('Scope Value', $scope.groupby);
            console.log('Watch value', this.last);
            console.log('new table',$scope.tableParams);
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is too late, but I thought better to comment on this for others who seeking for a answer for the same issue.

I also had the same issue and managed to fix by following the example in following URL.

https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/src/scripts/04-controller.js

I just added the following code line into my code after 'ngTableParams' instance creation.

```
$scope.params.settings().$scope = $scope;
```

Comment: I think somehow the settings().$scope getting null during the $scope. params.reload(). I was able to get rid of this error by adding a timeout to reload() as well. But it is not a good method. I think the reload() is not waiting till we get the result properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is when it started working for me. I added the scope in the params.settings.

```
controller: function() {
...
 $scope.myTableParams = new ngTableParams({
.
},{
...
getData: function ($defer, params) {
   if (params.settings().$scope == null) {
         params.settings().$scope = $scope;
   }
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374896/in-ngtables-running-scope-tableparams-reload-for-the-third-time-results-in-t/26174211#26174211) take a look ,setting up all parameters for *ngTableParams* solved the problem