# In ngTables, running $scope.tableParams.reload() for the third time results in TypeError: Cannot set property '$data' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

This error is in regards to the [ngTable](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) plugin for AngularJS.

I seem to be having a really weird error.  Basically, I can run `$scope.tableParams.reload()` twice with no problem, but on the third execution, and every following one, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '$data' of null at [removed]/ng-table.js:411:55
```

I believe this is all the relevant code, but if anything is missing let me know:

```
$scope.lookupAddress = function(address){       
    var url = 'https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?cors=true&active='+address;
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.clearTableData();
    $http.get(url).success(function(data){
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.loaded = true;
        $scope.loadError = false;
        glob = data;

        //I believe the next few for loops, and the assignment of transactions, is not relevant to finding the code.  That being said, I've included it because bugs hide where you least expect it.
        for (i = data.txs.length -1; i > -1; i-- ){
            var inputAddr = []; 
            for (z = 0; z < data.txs[i]['inputs'].length; z++){
                inputAddr.push(data.txs[i]['inputs'][z]['prev_out']['addr'])
            }
            var outputAddr = [];
            for (z = 0; z < data.txs[i]['out'].length; z++){
                outputAddr.push(data.txs[i]['out'][z]['addr'])
            }
            transactions[i] = {
                'Hash' : data.txs[i]['hash'],
                'Amount' : data.txs[i]['result'] / 100000000,
                'Balance' : data.txs[i]['balance'] / 100000000,
                'InputAddress' : inputAddr,
                'OutputAddress' : outputAddr,
                'Date' : timeConverter(data.txs[i]['time'])
            };
        };

        //You can also ignore this too... probably.
        $scope.output = {
            'BTC' : data.wallet.final_balance / 100000000, //Response in satoshi, so have to divide.
            'Address' : address,
            'Total Received': data.addresses[0].total_received / 100000000,
            'Total Sent': data.addresses[0].total_sent / 100000000,
            'Transactions' : transactions
        };
        //Enables new data to be loaded, e.g. on a new address.
        if ($scope.tableParams){
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        } 
        data = transactions;
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            
            count: 5,           // items per page
            sorting: {
                Date: 'desc' 
            }
        }, {
            total: transactions.length, 
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                data = transactions;
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

            }
        });
    }).
    error(function(data){
        $scope.loadError = true;
    });
}

$scope.clearTableData = function(){
    transactions = [];
    $scope.output = {}
    if ($scope.tableParams){
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
    } 
}
```

Comment: The code you're using to get your data (which you've marked as potentially unrelated) _really_ is irrelevant; the problem lies in the $scope.tableParams.reload() call. [Suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5441134), but it got rejected.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is too late, but I thought better to comment on this for others who seeking for a answer for the same issue.

I also had the same issue and managed to fix by following the example in following URL.

https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/src/scripts/04-controller.js

I just added the following code line into my code after 'ngTableParams' instance creation.

```
$scope.params.settings().$scope = $scope;
```

Comment: This helped me avoid the "null" error, but it's still not reloading the table content. I've got the reload in a different controller from the one in which I create the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
,
$scope: { $data: {} }
```

after:

```
getData: function($defer, params) {
                data = transactions;
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

            }
```

Comment: This won't work, as ng-table expects a real $scope, not a fake one.

Comment: Yeah, it helps avoid the error but won't update the data, which misses the point really.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When you initialize `ngTableParams`, you need to specify all parameters: `page`, `count`, `total`, and `counts`, even if you are not using paging, because otherwise the `$scope` property of setting  will be set to null somehow during merging all settings together.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and solved it by adding reload:

```
$scope.tableParams as below 
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 25,
            ***reload: $scope.tableParams***
        },
```