# ng-Table not rendering new data when reloading request

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

i have page with ng-table which works fine with initial data. I have a select box which send server request based on the option selected and then Iam getting new data to angular but is not updated with ng-table.

Here is my view:

```
<section data-ng-controller="ReportsController">
<div class="plain-box">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-show="column.visible"
                class="text-center sortable" ng-class="{
                    'sort-asc': tableParams.isSortBy(column.field, 'asc'),
                    'sort-desc': tableParams.isSortBy(column.field, 'desc')
                  }"
                ng-click="tableParams.sorting(column.field, tableParams.isSortBy(column.field, 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc')">
                {{column.title}}
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns" sortable="column.field">
                {{user[column.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('reports').controller('ReportsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Reports', '$filter', 'ngTableParams',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Reports, $filter, ngTableParams ) {
    $scope.reportBillingPeriod = 0;
    $scope.$watch('reportBillingPeriod', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.findReportData( newValue );
    });
    //$scope.reportBillingData = 0;


    $scope.findReportData = function( selectedMonth ){
        var selectedPeriod = selectedMonth;
        if( selectedPeriod === null )
        selectedPeriod = '0';
        $scope.customers_report = Reports.customer_report({
        monthReport: selectedPeriod
        }, function( result ){
        var data = result.customers;
        $scope.columns = [
            { title: 'Account Name', field: 'accountName', visible: true, filter: { 'name': 'text' } },
            { title: 'Gross Revenue', field: 'planTotalAmount', visible: true }
        ];

   $scope.$watch('result', function () {
        $scope.tableParams.settings().$scope = $scope;
        $scope.tableParams.reload(); 
    });

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,          // count per page
            filter: {
            name: 'O'       // initial filter
            }
        }, {
            total: data.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            //$scope.reportBillingData = new Date();
            }
        });
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$scope.$watch('result', function () {
        $scope.tableParams.settings().$scope = $scope; <<--nested scope is replacing!!
        $scope.tableParams.reload(); 
    });
```

*ngTable* directive create nested scope which inculde all settings for directive to work,so you shoudn't replace it with scope of ReportsController 
you need to remove this row
`$scope.tableParams.settings().$scope = $scope;`

And you need to specify all parameters for *ngTable*,please have a look
here [In ngTables, running $scope.tableParams.reload() for the third time results in TypeError: Cannot set property '$data' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374896/in-ngtables-running-scope-tableparams-reload-for-the-third-time-results-in-t/26174211#26174211)

**UPDATE**
and also it's better take ngTableParams intialization and $watch for result outside findReportData  function in order to prevent errors and unnecessary re-initialization

**UPDATE 2**
i set up [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIPTvIAJ1m5EY3t77QhC),try to make it more look like original question,and mock httpservice,
but that's not matter,all data access must be going inside `getData` func in `ngTableParams` and when set up all filter you need to call(or maybe just using `$watch` like in plunk) you have to call `$scope.tableParams.reload();` ,you can try to type some numbers in input above and data will be updating without problem.all code related to sorting ,pagging and filtering is removed for clarity,
so `getData` look like following:

```
 getData: function($defer, params) {
        var selectedPeriod = $scope.reportBillingPeriod ; //selectedMonth;
         if( selectedPeriod === null )
    selectedPeriod = '0';
    $scope.customers_report = Reports.get({   //Reports.customer_report({
    monthReport: selectedPeriod
    }, function(result ){
    var data = result.customers;
     $scope.tableParams.total(data.length);


    var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

    });      

        }
```

and watching for filter change look like follow:

```
 $scope.reportBillingPeriod = 0;
    $scope.$watch('reportBillingPeriod', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.tableParams.reload(); 
     });
```

**UPDATE 3**
removed duplication of invocation `getData` func,edited [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jKvqGXZE9wwAI0ejn3dS)
the issue was laid in `$watch` of `reportBillingPeriod` variable,so in order to prevent second data upload we have to check how values is changed, like here

```
$scope.reportBillingPeriod = defaultValue;
    $scope.$watch('reportBillingPeriod', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        //this how we prevent second call
        if (newValue!=oldValue)
        $scope.tableParams.reload(); 
     });
```

Comment: i moved the $watch to outside of findReportData function, then commented out the `$scope.tableParams.settings().$scope = $scope;`. Then manually assigning the values of `page`, `count`, `total`, and `counts`. but still not working.

Comment: ohh,there is some more need to make it work,let me set up plunk a little bit later,and figure out what's the problem

Comment: sorry for late response ,please check plunk in answer

Comment: When first time loading, the getData gets called twice. Is there any way we can control?

Comment: Added if($scope.reportBillingPeriod !=0) $scope.tableParams.reload();. Now works fine.