# Pagination not working after loading JSON data on Ng-Table

Tags: json, angularjs, pagination, xmlhttprequest, ngtable

I followed the example on [http://bazalt-cms.com/](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1) for the pagination but using `$http.get` instead of hard-coding a variable in the controller.

```
  $http.get("data.json").success(function(data){
       $scope.dataset = data;
   }
```

I also moved the `$scope.tableParams` inside the `$http.get`

```
$http.get("data.json").success(function(data){
     $scope.dataset = data;

     $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
      ...
    }
});
```

and changed the `data` variable to `$scope.dataset`

```
total: $scope.dataset.length, // length of data
getData: function($defer, params) {
        $defer.resolve($scope.dataset.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));}
```

Everything works fine besides the pagination is now not working [See Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7UUHgS4N038hLXhAwFdC?p=preview)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>I've been working with `ng-table` for a while. When I tried using variable names other than `$data` or `data`, it doesn't seem to work. So I suggest you should stick to using `$data` or `data` instead of any other variable names like `dataset`.</s>

Here's a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dOoFAP4YrnhehCCpBqZ0?p=preview).

**UPDATE** :

Looks like I missed to see what was really wrong in the OP's question. As *Tyler Collier* and *yunus kala* mentioned in the comments, you just have to use `$data` like `<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">` instead of `<tr ng-repeat="user in dataset">`. And it doesn't matter if you use `data` or `dataset` in your controller code.

Comment: interesting, will read more about it later, thanks for the solution.

Comment: your ng-repeat you must use $data

Comment: This is wrong. See http://plnkr.co/edit/IUzNp0bHdRZT4NUanmyz?p=preview, where I use `dataset`. At first, I was tempted to believe this answer because of the upvotes and because (as a test) removing the ng-table.js source `ng-table/pager.html`'s attribute that looks like the following made it work: `ng-if="params.data.length`. But that's not the real issue. Is this answer referring to scope level variables, as in, properties? Otherwise it makes no sense. I'd love more detail.

Comment: @yunuskula Thanks. Didn't see that.

Comment: I've updated my plunker to show that you don't need to use $data in the ng-repeat (although it might be considered convenient).

Comment: My previous plunker used the latest version of the ng-table library. I wondered if the problem was from version 0.3.0 so I [made another plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IUzNp0bHdRZT4NUanmyz?p=preview) with the old version, but it still has nothing to do with $data or data.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here [ng-Table not rendering new data when reloading request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205534/ng-table-not-rendering-new-data-when-reloading-request/26208093#26208093)  
first  should apply directive `ng-repeat` for `$data` variable,and move `ngtableParams` initialization outside `success` callback, and put inside `getData` all logic for data acsess