# How to reload ngtable using $scope.tableParams.reload();?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ng-table in angular js. My problem is delete one record in my table the data is not reloaded. this is my code

```
 myapp.controller('aamListAssignment', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngTableParams', function ($scope, $http, ngTableParams) {

        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.listPromise = null;
        $scope.$watch("data", function () {
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });    

        $scope.list = function () {
            $scope.listPromise = $http.get('./ccs/assignment/all').success(function (data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1, // show first page
                    count: 2           // count per page
                }, {
                    counts: [],
                    total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {
                        $defer.resolve($scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    }
                });
            });
        };
        $scope.removeAssignment = function (id) {
            $scope.value = true;
            $scope.Url = "./ccs/assignment/removeAssignment/" + id;
            $http.get($scope.Url).success(function (data) {
                console.log('after delete: ' + $scope.id);
               // $location.path('aam/listAssignment/');
                $scope.list();
            });
        };

        $scope.list();
    }]);
```

Execute time two types of errors occurred in a console page that is

```
"Error: $scope.tableParams is undefined..............
```

and

```
"Error: h.$scope is null..........
```

please help me to this problem.

I am using another way, this time reload is working,but pagination not working.the code is

```
myapp.controller('aamListAssignment', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngTableParams', function ($scope, $http, ngTableParams) {

    $scope.tableParams = {};
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.listPromise = null;
    $scope.list = function () {
        $scope.listPromise = $http.get('./ccs/assignment/all').success(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });

    };
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1, // show first page
        count: 6           // count per page
    }, {
        counts: [],
        total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve($scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });

    $scope.removeAssignment = function (id) {
        $scope.value = true;
        $scope.Url = "./ccs/assignment/removeAssignment/" + id;
        $http.get($scope.Url).success(function (data) {
            console.log('after delete: ' + $scope.id);
            $scope.list();
        });
    };
    $scope.list();

}]);
```

Comment: your `$scope.$watch("data", function ()` run faster than ngtableparams initialize that's why is undefined

Comment: you shoud move `ngTableParams` outside `success` callback in controller

Comment: that time the pagination is not working

Comment: becase of `counts: [],` ,this setting disable pagination,remove this row

Comment: that time only show tabs(10,25,50,100),pagination tabs not showing

Comment: in html are you bind to `$data` variable?,please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373825/pagination-not-working-after-loading-json-data-on-ng-table)

Comment: ok then, at this point most effective way to solve this ,is set up plunk,can you make to reproduce bug?

Comment: ngTableParams move in outside the pagination is not working in plunk also.  http://plnkr.co/edit/ojamR80otcyEQOTax7b8?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just request the data, and then just paginate on array, there is no problem.
However if you need to paginate on every request then have a look [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zuzcma?p=info), and don't forget
to iterate over `$data`

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
```

### Edit

in your plunk you should add `total` call, similar to the code below:

```
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
    //needed for pagination!!
    params.total(data.length);
    $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
```

### Edit 2

your working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ti6C2lhs2WGCrr7urN17?p=preview)
with editing above